# ¿Donde colocar ProgressBar para un login? Android Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

Veréis, tengo una pantalla de login que se conecta con Firebase para registrar y logear usuarios, pues bien, me gustaría que se mostrara un ProgressBar circular indeterminado cada vez que registro un usuario o un usuario hace login, pero no consigo dar con donde colocarlo exactamente. Conseguí que se mostrara pero no cuando pulso el botón, sino un segundo después y me gustaría que fuera nada mas pulsar el botón. Os dejo el código:

El Activity donde tengo el login:

```
package com.isaac.appet;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText etEmailLogin;
private EditText etPassLogin;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressBar pbProgressLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    etEmailLogin = findViewById(R.id.etEmailLogin);
    etPassLogin = findViewById(R.id.etPassLogin);
    Button btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    Button btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    pbProgressLogin = findViewById(R.id.pbProgressLogin);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void userRegister() {

    String email = etEmailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass = etPassLogin.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No olvides escribir tu email, lo necesitas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;

    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Que cabeza la tuya, no has metido la clave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }



    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Te has registrado con éxito, tus mascotas lo agradecen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Vaya, no he podido registrarte, lo siento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

}

private void userLogin() {

    final String email = etEmailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass = etPassLogin.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No olvides escribir tu email, lo necesitas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Que cabeza la tuya, no has metido la clave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }



    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();


                    } else {
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Este usuario no está registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnRegister:

            userRegister();
            break;

        case R.id.btnLogin:

            userLogin();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

El XML del ProgressBar:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E2E2E2"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmailLogin"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FF8D00"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_user_login"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/hint_login_email"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassLogin"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etEmailLogin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#FF8D00"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_pass_login"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/hint_login_pass"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etPassLogin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#FC6600"
            android:text="@string/button_login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#FC6600"
            android:text="@string/button_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90pt"
        android:contentDescription="Imagen de logotipo de la pantalla de login"
        android:src="@drawable/isotipo" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/pbProgressLogin"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

He intentado dentro de los métodos al logearse, pero eso, se muestra un segundo después y me gustaría que fuera algo instantáneo. No se si me falta algo por meter aparte del .showVisibility que es lo que uso para mostrar y quitar el progreso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los metodos `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` y `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` son asyncronos, esto quiere decir que no sabes cuando vas a terminar, por ende, el progressBar deberia empezar antes de estos metodos y terminar dentro de sus callbacks de exito o fallo.

```
private void userRegister() {

    String email = etEmailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass = etPassLogin.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No olvides escribir tu email, lo necesitas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;

    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Que cabeza la tuya, no has metido la clave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }


    pbProgressLogin.visibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Te has registrado con éxito, tus mascotas lo agradecen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     pbProgressLogin.visibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                             pbProgressLogin.visibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            pbProgressLogin.visibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Vaya, no he podido registrarte, lo siento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

}
```

y para el login

```
private void userLogin() {

    final String email = etEmailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass = etPassLogin.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No olvides escribir tu email, lo necesitas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Que cabeza la tuya, no has metido la clave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }


    pbProgressLogin.visibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        pbProgressLogin.visibility(View.GONE);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();


                    } else {
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                            pbProgressLogin.visibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                          pbProgressLogin.visibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Este usuario no está registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

}
```

Recuerda que tu progress deberia estar oculto antes de apretar el boton

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/pbProgressLogin"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>
```

Comment: Vale, eso de que estuviera oculta era lo que me faltaba. Ya decía yo que cuando iniciaba la aplicación me aparecería y no sabía donde colocarlo ya. Muchas gracias!